# How to set Button Height dynamically in RowDetails RowHeaderTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid with a Deails-View which shows another datagrid. This second grid is normally not shown. In the row header there is a button with a left arrow, when this is clicked, the details-grid is shown and the arrow changes to a down-arrow. This all works perfectly, but there is only a "small area" in the rowheader which accepts clicks. This is the code of my RowHeader-Template:

```
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  Click="DataGridRowHeader_Button_Click" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="40" >
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Style.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Grid >
                                                    <Border Background="Chartreuse" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5"></Border>
                                                    <Path Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,0 14,7 0,14 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>

                                 </Style.Setters>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=DetailsVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon" />
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                                                    <Grid >
                                                        <Border Background="LightCoral" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                                        <Path Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,0 14,0 7,14 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

The line with

> Setter Property = "Height" Value="125"

expands the button

[image]

but the button does not fit into the row header. With A small value, the button shrinks, and with a high button, the row header expands unnecessarily.

I tried to bind the Heigth-value to some parameters, e. g.

```
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs}}, Path=DetailsElement.ActualHeight}" />
```

(DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs captures the correct height-value when I look in code-behind:

```
    private void dg_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight);
    }
```

). Using

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRowDetails}}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
```

does not work either, the RowHeader is always expanded to a value which seems to be the height of the whole Master-Datagrid.

Any ideas how I can size the button correctly?
(Sorry for the colors, they are used only to see the different parts of the UI).

Hucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies within the `ControlTemplate` of the `DataGridRowHeader` where you can't properly align content (in your case your `Button`)

Instead of overriding the `ContentTemplate` every single time with full `Xaml` I tried another approach by using a `MarkupExtension`([AlignmentControlTemplateExtension](https://github.com/n0sale/stackoverflow/blob/master/WPF/AlignmentControlTemplateExtension.cs)), which does the necessary steps for me (clone and adjust the default `ControlTemplate`), so that I only have to do something like this

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{AlignmentControlTemplate Type={x:Type WhatEverType}}" />
```

---

To solve your problem you have to do only some few steps

1. Set the `DataGridRowHeader` `ControlTemplate`

   ```
   <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
           <Setter Property="Template" Value="{stackoverflow:AlignmentControlTemplate Type={x:Type DataGridRowHeader}}"></Setter>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
   ```
2. Set `VerticalContentAlignment` and/or `HorizontalContentAlignment` however you like it (in your case `VerticalContentAlignment=Stretch`)

   ```
   <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
           <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
           <Setter Property="Template" Value="{stackoverflow:AlignmentControlTemplate Type={x:Type DataGridRowHeader}}"></Setter>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
   ```
3. Some adjustments in your `Style.Triggers`

   Replace

   ```
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
   ```

   with

   ```
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   ```

---

**Edit** Final Result

```
<DataGrid>  
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter> <!-- Step 2 -->
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{stackoverflow:AlignmentControlTemplate Type={x:Type DataGridRowHeader}}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <!-- /Step 1 -->
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button  Click="DataGridRowHeader_Button_Click" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="40" >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid >
                                            <Border Background="Chartreuse" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5"></Border>
                                            <Path Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,0 14,7 0,14 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style.Setters>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=DetailsVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" /> <!-- Step 3 -->
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                                            <Grid >
                                                <Border Background="LightCoral" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                                <Path Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,0 14,0 7,14 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi nosale, thank you for helping me. But I do not know exactly which parts of my code I have to replace with yours. Does my button go to your AlignmentControlTemplate? Hucky

Comment: @Hucky Added how the final result should look like (with marks where each step took place)

Comment: at the moment I do not understand completely how "AlignControlTemplateExtension" work, but in total the code works perfectly. I try to understand the code tomorrow. Thank you very much again. Hucky

Comment: your solution compiles and works perfectly, but in the xaml-designer I get an error like: myVM_AlignmentControlTemplateExtension_2_351035389 is for "Setter.Value" not valid. Supported are only MarkupExtensionTypes "DynamicResourceExtension" and "BindingBase" or derived types. Due to this error the design part of the editor does not show the UI. Do you have an idea how to fix? Hucky

Comment: @Hucky I googled around a bit and it seems that in our case this is only a design time issue. If I have time I'll take a closer look. One solution that  I found is using a `Binding` like so `{Binding Source={stackoverflow:AlignmentControlTemplate Type={x:Type DataGridRowHeader}},Mode=OneTime}`

Comment: nosale: works now with no errors at design time, thank you again. Hucky